# Input Voltage to Sawtooth oscillator Confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, dac

[image]
I have attached a schematic of a project that I am working on, it is following a design that has already been done and works well. My problem is regarding V7. now the schematic below works perfectly when V7 is a DC source of the required voltage, in this case 0.039V. But the actual source of V7 is from a microcontroller, which sends 12 bits to a DAC, which then outputs a voltage which is what V7 is simulating. My question is, wouldn't the output from the DAC be an AC waveform? However when I replace V7 with an AC waveform it doesn't function properly at all. what am I missing?

EDIT: The AC source only works when the frequency of the AC signal is 1Hz. would then be something expected from a DAC?

Comment: The output from the DAC will be a voltage representation of the number written into it. If you only write one number to it, or the same number multiple times, the output voltage will not fluctuate.

Comment: Why is that? I thought the whole purpose of a DAC was to convert a digital signal into a analogue wave?

Comment: What a DAC _does_ is output a voltage that represents the number written to the digital input. If you write a sequence of numbers that represents a set of values corresponding to successive points on a sinewave, then the output will be a sinewave. [Actually a step-wise approximation to a sinewave, which can then be filtered to reconstruct a smooth waveform]. As per my previous, if you write a single number, it will output a steady value. Its _purpose_ is whatever the circuit designer intended.